# google appengine 'upload' directive won't work as expected

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

As **upload** is a regular expression that matches files being uploaded to static vault, the following app.yaml handler should work with **'static/images/jpg'** directory only, shouldn't it?

```
- url: /images/(.*?)\.(jpg|png)          
  static_files: static/images/\2/data.\2          
  upload: static/images/jpg/(.*)
```

Both requests receive file data from server though 'static/images/jpg' is the only value for upload directive:

```
 wget http://application_url/images/data.jpg
 wget http: //application_url/images/data.png
```

Could you please describe the correct meaning of upload directive?

Comment: You say in your title "won't work as expected", but don't actually tell us what problem you're having. What is your actual question?

Comment: I expected that only http://application_url/images/data.jpg gave data response, because I marked static/images/jpg/(.*) as upload value. But http://application_url/images/data.png is also available. I suppose it should not, because static/images/png/ is not included in 'upload' directive value.

Comment: The files will be available if some other upload or static_dir directive causes them to be uploaded as static files.

Comment: The whole app.yaml consist of three urls:
    - url: /images/(.*?)\.(jpg|png)
      static_files: static/images/\2/data.\2
      upload: static/images/jpg/(.*)

    - url: /favicon.ico
      static_files: static/favicon.ico
      upload: static/favicon.ico

    - url: /.*
      script: home.py

There are no links to static/images/png directory as static files.

Comment: Are you seeing this behavior in dev_appserver.py, or are you seeing it in production? If I understand your question correctly, this is definitely unexpected behavior.

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue. Can you run appcfg.py with --noisy option and check whether the png file is unintentionally processed or not?

Answer (score 1):

> shouldn't it?

Yes it should.

> Could you please describe the correct meaning of upload directive?

Your understanding is correct, but something wrong is happening. I tried to reproduce this issue, but got no luck yet. Can you run appcfg.py with --noisy option and check whether the png file is unintentionally processed or not?